# Scala image compression and optimisation

Tags: java, scala, jpeg, scrimage

I've been looking into `Scala/Java` based image compression and optimisation libraries and https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage looked like a good choice until I found that the documentation was incorrect and got no support whatsoever from their Gitter channel.

Here's my `build.sbt` line for the dependency;

`libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-core" % "2.1.1"`

and the examples on the documentation show;
https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage/blame/master/README.md#L88

Which seems to be incorrect since I have no `writer` method in the `Image` class. Is the library no longer supported? Has anyone found workarounds for this?

Comment: maybe just open an issue at https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage/issues? the author seems very active on GitHub

Comment: @ashesh What is your question exactly. Are you trying to read / write an image ?

Comment: I've updated the readme for imageio and I'll add an answer to this question with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example on how to read/write.

```
  // bring in a writer into scope for later
  implicit val writer = PngWriter.NoCompression

  // the image.fromFile method will work out what the file type is, the ext is optional really
  val image = Image.fromFile(new File("input.jpeg"))

  // just playing about the with image. They are immutable.
  val modified = image.scale(2).brightness(1.2).flipY

  // output accepts a file, path, string etc and requires an implicit writer.
  val out = modified.output(new File("output.png"))
```